# Using Telnet with Android App

Tags: android, sockets, telnet, socketserver

I'm developing an App that opens a SocketServer and gets commands from telnet. Until I'm under the same LAN there are no problems and everything works. 
Trying with the phone network I can't reach the phone using telnet. There is any way to solve this problem? This is how I open the socket.

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

Comment: "phone network", as in cellular data? Not possible, unless your cell provider for some reason provides routable IPs for data devices. phones are invariably behind a carrier-grade NAT gateway and cannot be reached from "outside", and in some cases not even inside as client-to-client communications are generally frowned upon.

Comment: Yes I mean cellular data.. Are there alternatives that you recommend?